# In the Stern-Gerlach experiment, did right-handed spin-up particles go towards the North or South magnetic pole?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin

Just as it says above... I cannot find a straight answer, and I have tried...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this schematic](https://www.slideshare.net/surbhi1409/power-point-slideschapter03) in a power point presentation that may help:

[image: sterngerlach schematic]

> [Particles with non-zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stern%E2%80%93Gerlach_experiment) magnetic moment are deflected, due to the magnetic field *gradient*, from a straight path

So it is not the north or south pole that makes the difference , but the orientations of the incoming magnetic moments interacting with the gradient of the magnetic field. In this illustration of the south poles point towards either north or south depending on the moments angle with the direction of the beam.

The answer is, they go to either pole.